# how to get rid of method names when console.log a function?

Tags: javascript, function, console.log

something like this in the output:

```
{
  array x [a,b,c,d]
  ],
  method: [Function: method],
  method2: [Function: method2],
  method3: [Function: method3]
}
```

PS: this is the output not my code itself. It's just better to highlight it as code snipped

i just want to log the function without all that additional text for the methods.

I'm using VS Code + Node JS

Comment: What exactly is the object you are logging? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The `console` methods are tools for developers. If you want different output, write your own methods.

Comment: a variable which is holding the function

Comment: @Pointy i want it for now so i don't get confused so much. If i need it i would turn it on again